# Spring boot 1.3 M2 failed to start the embedded container

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to migrate a apring boot 1.2.5 to 1.3.0.M2, get the following exception...
Any suggestions?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: serverProperties,server.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1073)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
... 38 more
```

Comment: Obviously you configured two ServerProperties instances. But without your actual Spring configuration, there is not much more to say.

Comment: This is the problem, i do not have any configuration for the embedded container, either in code or the application.properties file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have run into a bug, see [Duplicate bean definition for ServerProperties when using Spring Session in a hierarchical context](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3476). It will be fixed in 1.3.0.RC1.